# Recording each channel using ALSA API

Tags: audio, signal-processing, raspberry-pi, alsa, pulseaudio

I'm using a playstation eye, plugged into a raspberry pi. I have the raspberry pi recognising the built in microphone array of the PSEye and I can sample input levels using

```
arecord -vv /dev/null -r 16000 -f S16_LE -c 4 -D iec958:CARD=CameraB409241,DEV=0 /dev/null < /dev/null
```

Now obviously this shows the levels for all 4 channels being summed together. What I wish to do is record each channel separately. Is this possible using the ALSA API?

I've looked through this http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/pcm.html

And took a look at this http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6735?page=0,2

But neither seemed to what I needed. This is also similar to sampling both channels of a stereo mic over ALSA as well I suppose. Eventually I want to be able to sample the dB from each microphone at a specific point in time.

Comment: Do you want to record, or to show the input level?

Comment: I don't want to save it to a file no, I need to do processing on the sound levels from each microphone so just showing each level is more what require..

Comment: What kind of processing?

Comment: I want to be able to do beam forming techniques using the sound pressure values.

Comment: What is the problem with that example program? Just replace two with four.

Comment: It merges the channels together, I would like each channel seperate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read into a separate buffer for each channel, replace SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED with [SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_NONINTERLEAVED](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___p_c_m.html#ga661221ba5e8f1d6eaf4ab8e2da57cc1a), and replace snd_pcm_readi with [snd_pcm_readn](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___p_c_m.html#gafea175455f1a405f633a43484ded3d8a).

Comment: Is there in configuration? CLI?

Comment: @Rougher This is about the interface between the application and the library. It cannot be affected from the outside.

Comment: I also need to record each channel separately but to separate file. Where can I start to read about it, because I don't understand your answer? Thank you.

Comment: Even it can be the same file, but with separate channels if it's possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65439370/recording-each-channel-without-mixing maybe you can help here. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to record each channel to independent audio files, then you can use this application :

https://github.com/flatmax/gtkiostream/blob/master/applications/ALSACaptureSplitter.C

It needs to be compiled, which is described here :
https://lists.audioinjector.net/pipermail/people/2020-March/000028.html

To use the application specify the base file name and the extension, for example :
`ALSACaptureSplitter /tmp/test wav`

It can record to many different audio file formats.

You can use the options to change the device, specify the recording time, channel count, etc. Here is the help printed out by the application :

```
     ./applications/ALSACaptureSplitter -h
     ALSACaptureSplitter : An application to capture input and save to 
 independent files.
    Usage:
         ALSACaptureSplitter [options] outFileNamePrefix ext
         e.g. ALSACaptureSplitter [options] /tmp/out wav
         -D : The name of the device : (-D hw:0)
         -c : The number of channels to open, if the available number is less, then it is reduced to the available : (-c 2)
         -t : The duration to sample for : (-t 2.1)
         -r : The sample rate to use in Hz : (-r 48000)
    AUDIO FILE FORMATS:The known output file extensions (output file formats) are the following :
    8svx aif aifc aiff aiffc al amb amr-nb amr-wb anb au avr awb caf cdda cdr cvs cvsd cvu dat dvms f32 f4 f64 f8 fap flac fssd gsm gsrt hcom htk ima ircam la lpc lpc10 lu mat mat4 mat5 maud mp2 mp3 nist ogg paf prc pvf raw s1 s16 s2 s24 s3 s32 s4 s8 sb sd2 sds sf sl sln smp snd sndfile sndr sndt sou sox sph sw txw u1 u16 u2 u24 u3 u32 u4 u8 ub ul uw vms voc vorbis vox w64 wav wavpcm wv wve xa xi
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)