# Recording each channel without mixing

Tags: raspberry-pi, audio-recording, alsa, channel

I am a new in this field, maybe what I ask it's impossible to implement.

What I try to do is - recording an audio with n-channels to WAV file with n-channels.

I use `arecord` utility:

```
arecord --format=S16_LE --channels=8 --rate=16000 --file-type=wav myfile.wav
```

In my input I see different channels:
[image]

But in output of recording I see all channels are mixed:
[image]

Is it possible to record WAV file without mixing channels?
Is it possible to record each channel to separate channel?

Comment: What are the capabilities of your hardware? (And how is this related to programming?)

Comment: I run it on Raspberry Pi 0w. How is related to programming - I run arecord from JAVA code and this code runs on tomcat.